# componentDidMount working only at first time screen load in react native

Tags: react-native

I have added alert in componentDidMount in react native app . Alert is showing then user open screen first time . when user go to second screen and then again come back to first screen by click on menu then alert is not showing . Please Help.

This is react native app .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';

import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
} from 'react-navigation';

import Screen1 from './pages/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './pages/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './pages/Screen3';

class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {

  toggleDrawer = () => {
    //Props to open/close the drawer
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  render() {
      Alert.alert("hello");
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          {/*Donute Button Image */}
          <Image
            source={require('./image/drawer.png')}
            style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

//For React Navigation 2.+ need to use StackNavigator instead createStackNavigator
//const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = StackNavigator({

//For React Navigation 3.+
const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the Screen1 will be indexed here
  First: {
    screen: Screen1,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 1',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

//For React Navigation 2.+ need to use StackNavigator instead createStackNavigator
//const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = StackNavigator({

//For React Navigation 3.+
const Screen2_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the Screen2 will be indexed here
  Second: {
    screen: Screen2,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 2',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

//For React Navigation 2.+ need to use StackNavigator instead createStackNavigator
//const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = StackNavigator({

//For React Navigation 3.+
const Screen3_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the Screen3 will be indexed here
  Third: {
    screen: Screen3,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Demo Screen 3',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

//For React Navigation 2.+ need to use DrawerNavigator instead createDrawerNavigator
//const DrawerNavigatorExample = DrawerNavigator({

//For React Navigation 3.+
const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({
  //Drawer Optons and indexing
  Screen1: {
    //Title
    screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 1',
    },
  },

  Screen2: {
    //Title
    screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 2',
    },
  },

  Screen3: {
    //Title
    screen: Screen3_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 3',
    },
  },
});
```

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample);

I expect hello alert when user open first screen every time but hello shows only once when user open app when user open screen screen and again come to first screen alert is not showing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `componentDidMount` only triggers when the component has been 
  mounted. Looking at the code it looks like you are using a stackNavigator.

Navigating on another screen with the stack wont actually unmount the first screen you viewed, keeping it active while you are on another screen.

That's the reason it gets triggered once

If you need to run a function everytime the screen gets viewed you can use the react navigation focusses events. Check the react-navigation docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html